# Set dropdown default based on separate variable in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, default, angularjs-filter

I have a drop down that has a few dependencies. I have managed to populate the list from a data set and filter it properly. The next step is choosing the default. This is complicated because the default is set somewhere else, so I need to go through the options and see if it matches the defined default and set it, otherwise leave it without a default.

My data set is filtered in ng-repeat to only keep the values associated with a variable `$scope.require = MUST` .

Here is the template for the first dropdown:

```
ng-repeat="option in firstList | filter: require: true"
```

I have a variable from a different data set that says what the default for the drop down should be. If the `option in firstList` equals this default number, `defnum`, it should be the default for the dropdown.

so if defnum = 4, I want the default in the dropdown list to be the last entry, where DefCom = 4.

```
"success" : true,
    "data" : 
        "this_info" : [{
                 "Req" : "MUST",
                 "DefCom" : "1",
}, {
                 "Req" : "NoMUST",
                 "DefCom" : "5"
}, {
                 "Req" : "MUST",
                 "DefCom" : "4"
}]}
```

Is there a way to do this in ng-model or do I have to write an angular.forEach loop? I've tried to write the angular.forEach loop but I only want to be looping through the values that have been filtered in ng-repeat, I don't want to have to rewrite that filter (unless I have to).

Comment: You should use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`, along with `ng-model`.  When you set the `ng-model` property to a value, it will automatically set the dropdown to that line item as the default, if the value appears in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular's `ng-selected` property to set the selected of the option based on another scope variable, like this:

```
  <option ng-selected="defnum == option.DefCom" ng-repeat="option in this_info | filter:{Req:'MUST'}:true">
    {{ option.DefCom }}
  </option>
```

[plnkr.co demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/BSIBwILLD2FbH5vRZ4Sc?p=preview)

Comment: @jenryb - Sorry, should have used `ng-selected`. I updated the answer and [the plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BSIBwILLD2FbH5vRZ4Sc?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help or not... but I was able to filter according to deep rooted property/object to help with search filtering.

This may be down the road of what your looking for, or at least apply the theory to your problem.

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in gamesList | filter:{attributes: {gameData : {vsTeam: searchText}}}" class="item item-button-right"> .....

</ul>
```